# Adding Two dates with different format in c#

Tags: c#

I have to dates one is in the format  `mm/dd/yyyy` which is (fromdate) and the other i.e. todate in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` and I wanted to find the difference between the two dates.

Or in otherwords, how do I bring them to same date format before subtracting the one day from the other in c#?

Comment: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did you do any research whatsoever?  What did you learn from that research?

Comment: yes, I did, the problem is all of them talk about how you can convert them to string, what I wanted is to bring all dates of different format to one common date format which I can add, subtract... once I got the string format when I convert it to DateTime either using DateTime.Parse or Convert.ToDateTime the dates tend to remain as mm/dd/yyyy (fromdate) and dd/mm/yyy (todate)

Comment: Are they `DateTime` values or `string` values? `DateTime` values don't _have_ a format, only strings that _represent_ dates do.  There should be no issue comparing `DateTime` values _regardless_ of the format that they were as strings.

Comment: the to date was string converted to DateTime and the from date was DateTime collected from date time picker control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to something like:

```
var dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("02/14/2016", "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dateTo = DateTime.ParseExact("16/02/2016", "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = (dateTo - dateFrom).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help